# Permutation test for comparing sets of correlations

Tags: correlation, permutation-test, fisher-transform

I would like to compare two sets of n=100 Pearson correlation coefficients. In particular, I would like to test whether the means of these two sets of correlations differ significantly.

After some research online, I found a lot of recommendations for comparing individual pairs of correlations coefficients but only [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/how-to-test-the-difference-between-2-sets-of-pearson-correlations) thread that seems to discuss the setting I'm interested in, i.e. comparing sets of correlation coefficients.

In this thread, [one suggestion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368095) is to run a t-test on the Fisher-Z-transformed correlation coefficients. However, [another suggestion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365804) is to run a permutation test.

The second suggestion has not gotten any attention, however, I find it interesting because it seems more flexible than a t-test. Therefore, I would like to use a permutation test.

Now my question is: In the above-described setting is it necessary to perform the permutation test on the Fisher-Z-transformed correlations, or can I equivalently run it on the "raw" correlations?

In Python code, what I would like to do is this:

```py
def get_permutation_statistics(x, y, n_permutations=50_000):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    statistics = np.zeros(n_permutations)
    total = np.hstack((x, y))
    for i in tqdm(range(n_permutations)):
        shuffled = rng.permuted(total)
        x_p, y_p = np.split(shuffled, 2)
        assert x_p.shape == y_p.shape
        mean_diff = np.mean(x_p) - np.mean(y_p)
        statistics[i] = mean_diff.item()
    return statistics

# observed difference
init_mean_diff = np.mean(x) - np.mean(y)

# permutation statistics
statistics = get_permutation_statistics(x, y)

# get p-value (two-tailed)
p = np.sum(np.abs(statistics) > np.abs(init_mean_diff)) / n_permutations
```

where `x` and `y` are two 1-dim. arrays containing the correlation coefficients, either "raw" or Fisher-Z-transformed.